# How to extract ordered boundary cycle in CGAL?

Tags: c++, mesh, cgal

I'm new to `CGAL`, I'm trying to find out how to extract ordered boundary cycle in CGAL.

Assume there has only one boundary in my mesh.

`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::extract_boundary_cycles` extracts boundary cycles as a list of halfedges, with one halfedge per border.

`CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::border_halfedges` collects the border halfedges of a surface patch defined as a face range.

None of them collect ordered boundary cycle.

I guess this a common task,
are there built in function in CGAL to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have one border edge per cycle, you can use [`CGAL::halfedges_around_face()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/BGL/group__PkgBGLIterators.html#ga37229df31508a78eb4acdaf907e637e5) to iterate over all edges of a cycle.